# Axios get request taking too long to respond

Tags: ajax, vuejs2, axios

I have a GET api and I am calling it using axios.get in my Vue js application but it is taking too long to get me response.

Is there any way I can increase the performance?  Any hint or link will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: How much time is too long? What code did you use specifically to to the GET request?

Answer (score -1):

How much data are you querying from the api? or What type of actions are performed in the backend?

Most of the time when an api call takes a long time to respond usually has to do with the api / server  not the client i.e over querying of data. You can try reducing / optimizing the action / process performed by the server, reducing the amount of data queried and returned. remove the unnecessary data like timestamps and unneeded information.